# Same Template struct, C++

Tags: c++, templates, std, is-same

Consider I have structs RGB and ARGB.

```
template<typename T>
struct RGB {
    T r,g,b;
};

template<typename T>
struct ARGB {
    T a,r,g,b;
}
```

Now I define them by following.

```
using RGB_888 = RGB<unsigned char>;
using RGB_Float = RGB<float>;
using ARGB_8888 = ARGB<unsigned char>;
using ARGB_Float = ARGB<float>;
```

At some point I want to convert from one rgb to another and from rgb to argb. So I do the following.

```
template<typename Source, typename Dest>
void convert(const Source& source, Dest& dest)
{

}
```

and it shall work like this.

```
RGB_888 rgb888{123,22,311};
RGB_Float rgbFloat;
convert<RGB_888,RGB_Float>(rgb888,rgbFloat);

RGB_888 rgb888(123,22,132};
ARGB_Float argbFloat;
convert<RGB_888,ARGB_Float>(rgb888,argbFloat);
```

The problem is that *I cannot detect whether `typename Source` and `typename Dest` are from the same **Color Model** or not, and I need that for correct conversion*. In other words if some `typename T1`  is a hybrid typename `A<B>` and another `typename T2` is a hybrid typename `A1<B1>` How can I tell whether `typename A` and `typename A1` are the same or not? If I had all `A B A1 B1` typenames in my `convert()` function , I could tell by checking `std::is_same<A<B>,A1<B>>::value` But If I declare my function templates like that I'll end up unable to use `convert<RGB_888,ARGB_Float>(rgb888,argbFloat);` this signature (but I could use it with RGB and ARGB)

Please note: There are many other color models in my program, these are just for example.

Comment: 1) By "same Color Model", do you mean src and dest are both RGB _or_ both ARGB? 2) What pairs are desired? (RGB888, RGBFloat). (RGB888, ARGB888). And (RGB888, ARGBFloat) also? So what pairs are not allowed? Or do you just want to check whether Source/Dest are the same to provide a specialised implementation?

Comment: @TrebledJ the latter :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want overloads

```
template<typename Source, typename Dest>
void convert(const RGB<Source>& source, RGB<Dest>& dest)
{
// ...
}

template<typename Source, typename Dest>
void convert(const RGB<Source>& source, ARGB<Dest>& dest)
{
// ...
}
```

with usage

```
RGB_888 rgb888{123,22,311};
RGB_Float rgbFloat;
convert(rgb888, rgbFloat);

RGB_888 rgb888(123,22,132};
ARGB_Float argbFloat;
convert(rgb888, argbFloat);
```

but output parameter is strange, I think you can do

```
template <typename Dest, typename Source>
RGB<Dest> toRGB(const RGB<Source>& source)
{
// ...
}

template <typename Dest, typename Source>
ARGB<Dest> toARGB(const RGB<Source>& source)
{
// ...
}
```

With usage

```
RGB_888 rgb888{123, 22, 311};
RGB_Float rgbFloat = toRGB<float>(rgb888);

RGB_888 rgb888(123, 22, 132};
ARGB_Float argbFloat = toARGB<float>(rgb888);
```

Comment: no, sry this is not the syntax I would like((

Comment: For the `toRGB`, you might have `toRGB<RGB_Float>(rgb888)`. Fpr `convert`, to keep your syntax, you need extra layer (but seems strange to provide explicitly deducible types).

Comment: @HrantNurijanyan How is the overload solution not solve your problem? It follows the syntax you specified. (Well, except it automatically deduces the template, but that's a _good_ thing.) Can you clarify?

Comment: I found a solution, I'll post as an answer.